# Source of documentation for a standard JSON document structure?

Tags: json

I am working on a (.NET) REST API which is returning some JSON data.  The consumer of the API is an embedded client.  We have been trying to establish the structure of the JSON we will be working with.  The format the embedded client wants to use is something I have not seen before in working with JSON.  I suggested that it is no "typical" JSON.  I was met with the question "Where is 'typical' JSON format documented"?

As an example of JSON I "typically" see:

```
{
    "item" : {
        "users": [ ... list of user objects ... ],
        "times": [   ... list of time objects ...],
    }
}
```

An example of the non-typical JSON:

```
{
    "item" : [
        {  
            "users": [ ... list of user objects ... ]  
        },
        {
            "times": [   ... list of time objects ...]
        },
    ]
}
```

In the second example, item contains an array of objects, which each contain a property whose value is an array of entities.  This is valid JSON. However, I have not encountered another instance of JSON that is structured this way when it is not an arbitrary array of objects but is in fact a set list of properties on the "item" object.

In searching json.org, stackoverflow.com and other places on the interwebs I have not found any guidelines on why the structure of JSON follows the "typical" example above rather than the second example.

Can you provide links to documentation that would provide recommendations for one format or the other above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a link, but just straightforward answer: Items are either indexed (0, 1, 2, ...) or keyed (users, times). No matter what software you use, you can get at indexed or keyed data equally easily and quickly. But not with what you call "non-typical" JSON: To get at the users, I have to iterate through the array and find one dictionary that has a key "users". But there might be two or more dictionaries with that key. So what am I supposed to do then? If you use JSON schema, the "non-typical" JSON is impossible to check. In iOS, in the typical case I write

```
NSArray* users = itemDict [@"users"];
```

For the non-typical JSON I have to write

```
NSArray* users = nil;
for (NSDictionary* dict in itemArray)
  if (dict [@"users"] != nil)
    users = dict [@"users"];
```

but that still has no error checking for multiple dicts with the key "users". Which is an error that in the first case isn't even possible. So just tell them what the are asking for is rubbish and creates nothing but unnecessary work. For other software, you probably have the same problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You raised a point I hadn't thought of about potentially having duplicates in the array of objects.  "Rubbish" is a fitting description, too.